# Regarding memory consumption in python with urllib2 module

Tags: python, http, python-2.7, memory, memory-management

PS: I have a similar question with Requests HTTP library [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22687952/understanding-memory-consumption-increase-in-python-using-requests-http-library).

I am using python v2.7 on windows 7 OS. I am using  **urllib2** module. I have two code snippets. One file is named as `myServer.py` The `server` class has 2 methods named as `getName(self,code)` and `getValue(self)`.
The other script named as `testServer.py` simply calls the methods from the `server` class to retrieve the values and prints them. *The `server` class basically retrieves the values from a Server in my local network. So, unfortunately I can't provide you the access for testing the code.*

**Problem**: When I execute my `testServer.py` file, I observed in the task manager that the memory consumption keeps increasing. Why is it increasing and how to avoid it? If I comment out the following line

```
print serverObj.getName(1234)
```

in `testServer.py` then there is **no** increase in memory consumption.

I am sure that the problem is with the `getName(self,code)` of the `server` class. But unfortunately, I couldn't figure out what the problem is.

**Code:** Please find the code snippets below:

```
#This is the myServer.py file

import urllib2
import json
import random

class server():
    def __init__(self):
        url1 = 'https://10.0.0.1/'
        username = 'user'
        password = 'passw0rd'
        passwrdmgr = urllib2.HTTPPasswordMgrWithDefaultRealm()
        passwrdmgr.add_password(None, url1, username, password)
        authhandler = urllib2.HTTPBasicAuthHandler(passwrdmgr)
        opener = urllib2.build_opener(authhandler)
        urllib2.install_opener(opener)
    def getName(self, code):
        code = str(code)
        url = 'https://10.0.0.1/' + code
        response = urllib2.urlopen(url)
        data = response.read()
        name = str(data).strip()
        return name
    def getValue(self):
        value = random.randrange(0,11)
        return value
```

The following is the `testServer.py` snippet

```
from myServer import server
import time

serverObj = server()
while True:
    time.sleep(1)
    print serverObj.getName(1234)
    print serverObj.getValue()
```

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is question is quite similar to my other question. So I think the answer is also quite similar. The answer can be found here https://stackoverflow.com/a/23172330/2382792